# Can't connect vertices of two objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

Cant connect two vertices of separate objects. Whenever I press "F" while two vertices are selected it splits them into four unconnected ones. No modifiers. Checked for doubles. Scale applied. Also tried CTRl+J  Please help!

[image: Before pressing "F"]

[image: After]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question. They are two separate objects. You can't connect them. What happened here is blender has filled an n-gon around each vertex. You must select both the objects in object mode and join them if you want to connect them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply